# Target only text and not nested elements

Tags: javascript, nested

I need to manipulate only the text of a nested list without touching the next ul. I have this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some text here
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>ipsum dolor</li>
            <li>Another text here
                <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to wrap the inner text in a span so I will have this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Some text here</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>ipsum dolor</li>
            <li><span>Another text here<span>
                <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to add a span to all items of the inner list or only the last one?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (the inserted span element has a red text color):

You first select the desired li element ('ul > li > ul > li:last-of-type') then you get the text node which contains "Another text here" (item.firstChild), create a span element with its content and replace it with your span.

```js
let item = document.querySelector('ul > li > ul > li:last-of-type');

let text = item.firstChild.textContent;
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = text;
span.style.color = 'red';

item.replaceChild(span, item.firstChild);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Some text here
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>ipsum dolor</li>
            <li>Another text here
                <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a mix with jQuery and vanilla, but that's what worked for me was:

```
$('.in-documents ul li').each(function() {
   var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();

    if($(this)[0].firstChild.textContent != "") {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = text;
        $(this)[0].firstChild.textContent = '';
        $(this).prepend(span);
    }
});
```